# Simple ranking algorithm in Groovy

Tags: algorithm, groovy, ranking

I have a short groovy algorithm for assigning rankings to food based on their rating.  This can be run in the groovy console.  The code works perfectly, but I'm wondering if there is a more Groovy or functional way of writing the code.  Thinking it would be nice to get rid of the `previousItem` and `rank` local variables if possible.

```
def food = [
  [name:'Chocolate Brownie',rating:5.5, rank:null],
  [name:'Fudge', rating:2.1, rank:null],
  [name:'Pizza',rating:3.4, rank:null],
  [name:'Icecream', rating:2.1, rank:null],
  [name:'Cabbage', rating:1.4, rank:null]]

food.sort { -it.rating }

def previousItem = food[0]
def rank = 1
previousItem.rank = rank
food.each { item ->
  if (item.rating == previousItem.rating) {
    item.rank = previousItem.rank
  } else {
    item.rank = rank
  }
  previousItem = item
  rank++
}

assert food[0].rank == 1
assert food[1].rank == 2
assert food[2].rank == 3
assert food[3].rank == 3    // Note same rating = same rank
assert food[4].rank == 5    // Note, 4 skipped as we have two at rank 3
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
def rank = 1
def groupedByRating = food.groupBy { -it.rating }
groupedByRating.sort().each { rating, items ->
  items.each { it.rank = rank }
  rank += items.size()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the groupBy idea, I'm a fan.  However I get a null pointer, I think related to the sort() call.

I removed the local variables by inlining the groupBy and injecting the initial rank of 1.

    food.sort { -it.rating }.groupBy { it.rating }.inject(1) { rank, group ->
      def items = group.value
      items.each { it.rank = rank }
      rank += items.size()
    }

(ugg, how to you format in a comment?)

Comment: It seems that the NullPointerException is a bug of former Groovy versions. I could reproduce it with Groovy 1.7.0. With Groovy 1.7.2 the code works as described.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it, but maybe this could work.

```
food.eachWithIndex { item, i ->
    if( i>0 && food[i-1].rating == item.rating ) 
        item.rank = food[i-1].rank
    else
        item.rank = i + 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the index based approach seems clean, inlining the sort { -it.rating } call makes it fit with my 'no local defs' requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative that doesn't use "local defs" with the groovy inject method:

```
food.sort { -it.rating }.inject([index: 0]) { map, current ->
    current.rank = (current.rating == map.lastRating ? map.lastRank : map.index + 1)
    [ lastRating: current.rating, lastRank: current.rank, index: map.index + 1 ]
}
```